# Replicating table in R with change in one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this table in R :

```
Name     ID    Year   Month  Date  
John     8     2017    7     16     
Carol    90    2017    7     30  
Bug      9     2017    7     1
```

I want to replicate this same table 4 times, all values should be the same. Except the Month column, which needs to be incremented by 1 every time. And the final table should look like this:

```
Name     ID    Year   Month  Date  
John     8     2017    7     16  
Carol    90    2017    7     30  
Bug      9     2017    7     1   
John     8     2017    8     16  
Carol    90    2017    8     30  
Bug      9     2017    8     1  
John     8     2017    9     16  
Carol    90    2017    9     30  
Bug      9     2017    9     1  
John     8     2017    10     16  
Carol    90    2017    10    30  
Bug      9     2017    10    1  
John     8     2017    11    16  
Carol    90    2017    11    30  
Bug      9     2017    11    1
```

Please point how to do this efficiently in R. Many thanks!

Comment: "Please point how to do this efficiently in R" ..... In R everything is efficient :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text = "Name ID Year Month Date
            John 8 2017 7 16
            Carol 90 2017 7 30
            Bug 9 2017 7 1", header = TRUE)
```

Then this is your dataframe repeating:

```
df2 = df[rep(rownames(df), 4),]
```

And this is it again, but with the months incremented:

```
df2$Month = df2$Month + rep(0:3, 3)
```

In the more general case:

```
m = 4 # <-- number of rows desired
df2 = df[rep(rownames(df), m), ]
df2$Month = df2$Month + rep(0:m, nrow(df))
```

Comment: For your final line, you want `df2$Month + rep(0:3, each=nrow(df))`.

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(df, rep(rownames(df), m), ) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: This worked: df2 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df),m),]. It was my mistake, Thanks for pointing out lebelinoz!

Comment: And the final line had to be like how Imo points out : df2$Month + rep(0:3, each=nrow(df))